# How to set two different colors for text in TextView in XML?

Tags: android, textview

I have two words inside TextView :

```
Hello world.
```

Now I want to colorize `world` to red color. 
How I can do that ONLY in XML itself without using java code (without using `Html.fromHtml()` as well)

Comment: I'm a little bit confuse for downvoting...Why?

Comment: A good question...should not be downvoted.

Comment: *I'm a little bit confuse for downvoting...Why?* *A good question...should not be downvoted.* ... yes, it should, because it is duplicate

Comment: @Selvin but he doesn't want to go the html tags way. The duplicate you mentioned has to use **(Html.fromHtml())** to work.

Comment: You would have to subclass `TextView` to do this, so technically you can't do it "ONLY in XML". It would be a pretty simple subclass, though.

Answer (score 6):

You can use *font* tag in string.xml as

```
<string name="hello">Hello <font fgcolor="red">World</font></string>
```

Comment: Won't that make him use **(Html.fromHtml())** in java to actually retrieve this string ?

Comment: @NishantDubey yeap.

Comment: No it wouldn't if he is setting the value using `setText(R.string.hello);` or in Layout xml

Comment: Checked just now. Not worked.

Comment: Because afterall those are *HTML TAGS* will work with (Html.fromHtml()) which he doesn't want

Comment: I just created an example and its working. Don't know what you are doing wrong. Its the code. `<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`